# String as input variable - R

Tags: arrays, r, string, object

I try to figure out how to solve this problem. I want to store different elements into an array such as xtrain1, xtrain2... xtrainN by using the paste() and seq() method. Also these elements represents a variable, which should be applied to the array function. The idea is to create a string of these elements and parse it to the array function, which recognized that this string are variables inside the function. Creating the vector seq_Xtrain it creates the elements for a desired number of logValues (e.g. 10) in a string. If I apply the different elements directly to the array function it works. I think the extraction of the elements inside the string does not work. Would be nice if someone can help me, thanks!

```
seq_Xtrain <- paste("xtrain", seq(from=1, to=logValue),sep="", collapse=", ")

### Output of seq_Xtrain
[1] "xtrain1, xtrain2, xtrain3, xtrain4, xtrain5, xtrain6, xtrain7, xtrain8, xtrain9, xtrain10"

x_train <<- array( c(seq_Xtrain), dim=c(dim(xtrain1),logValue)) 

####### For example this works
##x_train <<- array( c(xtrain1, xtrain2, xtrain3, xtrain4,xtrain5, xtrain6, 
##                     xtrain7, xtrain8,xtrain9, xtrain10, xtrain11, xtrain12,
##                     xtrain13, xtrain14, xtrain15, xtrain16,xtrain17, xtrain18, xtrain19, xtrain20), dim=c(dim(xtrain1),20)) 

### Received output
> x_train[2]
[1] "xtest1, xtest2, xtest3, xtest4, xtest5, xtest6, xtest7, xtest8, xtest9, xtest10, xtest11, xtest12, xtest13, xtest14, xtest15, xtest16, xtest17, xtest18, xtest19, xtest20"

### Desired Output
> x_train[2]
[1] 0.4444944
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not 100% sure what you want to do also because some reproducible sample data is missing. But look at this example where I use `get`:

```
logValue <- log(1:3)

xtrain1 <- log(1)
xtrain2 <- log(2)
xtrain3 <- log(3)

seq_Xtrain <- paste0("xtrain", 1:length(logValue))

x_train <- array(sapply(seq_Xtrain, get))
```

Get looks for objects of the desired name and retrieves their value. In this case this yields

```
> x_train
[1] 0.0000000 0.6931472 1.0986123
```

Comment: Sorry for the late respond, you saved my day! Did not know the get function to look for objects. Thank you!